# What is the maximum allowed round trip time (RTT) between 2 nodes?

Tags: consul, hashicorp

[Consul reference architecture](https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/consul/reference-architecture#failure-domains) mentions below statement -

*"In any case, there should be high-bandwidth, low-latency (sub 8ms round trip) connectivity between the failure domains."*

**What happens if the RTT is more than 8ms? What is the maximum allowed RTT between 2 nodes in a cluster?**

Answer (score 0):

This limitation primarily applies to latency between Consul servers. Excessive latency between the servers could cause instability with Raft which could affect the availability of the server clusters.

Clients, however, can operate with higher latency thresholds. HashiCorp is in the process of updating documentation to clarify this, and also list acceptable latency thresholds for client agents.